# Real-Time File Lock Handling

Tags: file-io, file-locking, inventory-management

I'm working on a multi-terminal POS system. Inventory levels and availability is quite straightforward when dealing with physical goods, but how would we handle this when dealing with virtual inventory? I mean, what if the stock level for item X is 1, and two, or more, operators are trying to place an order for it? Or, even if the balance available quantity is more than just 1, should the quantity be deducted or locked from the inventory file when an operator is processing an order for it, and then reinstated if the order is cancelled?

Thanks in advance.